Why is the Json deserializer not working?
I'm quite new to Json files and Blazor, and I was trying to deserialize a Json string, but when I try to fill a list with objects obtained via deserializer the list is full of null objects.
I'm also using Flurl, I don't know if it's of any relevance, but I'll just mention it to be sure.
The string I'm deserializing is this one :
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "DASHBOARD",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "description": "Accounting",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "description": "Anti-avoidance obligations",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "description": "Personal data",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "description": "Date",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "description": "Balance",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "description": "Communication",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "description": "F24 - F23 and communications",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "description": "Management",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "description": "StudyOK",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "description": "730",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "description": "770",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "description": "Fees",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "description": "Certification",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "description": "IMU",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "description": "ISA",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "description": "IVA",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "description": "PF",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "description": "SC",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "description": "SP",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "description": "Widget",
        "position": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "itemSections": [],
        "users": []
    }
]

This is the code :
var tokenTrimmed = token2.Split("\"token\":\"")[1].Split('"')[0].Trim();
result = await url.WithOAuthBearerToken(tokenTrimmed).GetStringAsync();

var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(result);


Console.WriteLine(jsonDocument.RootElement.ToString());

items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GridList>>(jsonDocument.RootElement);

This is the GridList Class :
@code {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public List<string> ItemSections { get; set; }
    public List<string> Users { get; set; }
}

And this is what I get:


Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Have you just tried this: JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GridList>>(yourJsonInput). Just not using JsonDocument and all that stuff.

Just tried, it sadly doesn't work

Create a separate .cs file called for example ItemDto.cs, or DTO/Item.cs. Razor components are not meant to be deserialized. Appart from that, JSON serializer is case sensitive by default

Does this answer your question? JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails

You have to put in the string directly (as a variable of course). Not using jsonDocument.RootElement.

@Michelle: Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/djSnz0

Ty @Liero, it worked! Also, I tried both with a razor component and with a class, it works both ways, should I keep the class instead of the razor component? If so, why?

So to summarize:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
});

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GridList>>(yourJsonAsString, options);

